# how to popToViewController with ARC and Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, poptoviewcontroller

anybody know how to popToViewController ?

example:
introvideo-> welcomeview & tutorialview-> mainviewcontroller-> scannerviewcontoller-> questionview ->(if answer correct -> correctView) else ->wrongView

how do i pop back to mainView controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to iterate through the `viewControllers` array of the navigation controller. You can identify the correct one by tag, class name, etc.

Answer (score 2):

based on what you have written It looks like MainViewController is the 4th ViewController on the navigation stack.

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[arrayOfViewControllers objectAtIndex:3] animated:YES];
```

should do the trick.